# How to revoke twitter API request after rate limit exceed?

Tags: php, twitter

I am working with Twitter API 1.1 and I am fetching tweets of a user.

I am using this code

```
<?php
        $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
        $requestMethod = "GET";
        $cursor = isset($cursor) ? $cursor : "-1";
        $getfield = "?cursor=" . $cursor . "&user_id=" . $user . "&count=10";
        $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);               
        $string  = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                ->performRequest();
        $tweets = json_decode($string, 1); 
        echo '<pre>';print_r($string);echo '</pre>';
 ?>
```

Is there way to recieve since_id after a particualr request so that I can requeue my function for the next request starting from the last recieved id?

For Example: In a single request I am fetching 0-1000 records, On my next request I want start from 1001th record.

Is it possible in twitter?

Answer (score 0):

If you made a request to a timeline without using since_id, and the most recent tweet you got back had the ID "123" then, after an interval, you can use that most recent tweet ID "123" as your since_id value to user_timeline. You would then get (up to 200) of the next most recent tweets posted by that user "since" they posted tweet "123".